# Posting to PHP link with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying to use a wamp server with my html site. I want to add a row to a table but nothing seems to work. I am using ajax to post the data to the php file and then using sql commands to update the table.

HTML Code

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onClick="PostJob();"> Submit </button>
```

Javascript code in HTML file:

```
    <script language="javascript">
    function PostJob() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/jobjobDatabase/update_job.php",
        data: {ProjectName: $("#ProjectName").val()}
        });
    }
    </script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_POST['ProjectName'])) {
    $ProjectName = $_POST['ProjectName']; //Project Name
    echo $ProjectName;




    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO postedjobs(ProjectName) 
                       VALUES('$ProjectName')");


    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "games successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or I should try? I have been googleing and reading/trying everything and nothing seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Have you opened the browser's console and observed the request / response? You'll find the solution there.

Comment: Check your browser's console and see if there's any errors reported. Try adding `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP script to see if the POST request is actually made.

Comment: You need to add a callback, and specify the JSON attribute to retrieve your PHP $response. $.ajax({ /* data */ }, function( response ){ /*callback*/ console.log(response) }, 'json');

Comment: Thanks guys i have spent 2 two days googleing it when the answer was right there in my console! Really appreciate it! Got it to work too! Ill edit my code for others to see.